Plotting with x and y values in the same column in ggplot2
I wish to create a scatter/line plot with a series for each patient with the x/y pairs derived from data from that patient's column. The small sample of the data looks like this:
Patient ID             1        2
Controll_Percent_1     0.000    0.000
Controll_Percent_2     0.035    0.000
Controll_Percent_3     0.035    0.039
Controll_Percent_4     0.053    0.053
Controll_Percent_5     0.088    0.066
Controll_Percent_6     0.088    0.066
Controll_Percent_7     0.105    0.092
Controll_Percent_8     0.123    0.171
Controll_Percent_9     0.158    0.263
Controll_Percent_10    0.158    0.224
Controll_Percent_11    0.197
Controll_Percent_12    0.211
Controll_Percent_13    0.276
Controll_Percent_14     
Controll_Percent_15     
Controll_Percent_16     
Controll_Percent_17     
Controll_Days_1        33        32
Controll_Days_2        378       128
Controll_Days_3        575       502
Controll_Days_4        951       633
Controll_Days_5        1127      800
Controll_Days_6        1324      853
Controll_Days_7        1512      999
Controll_Days_8        1887      1122
Controll_Days_9        2141      1312
Controll_Days_10       2331      1467
Controll_Days_11       1657
Controll_Days_12       2022
Controll_Days_13       2393
Controll_Days_14        
Controll_Days_15        
Controll_Days_16        

Each "Controll_Percent" pairs with a "Controll_days", describing the result y after x days following an operation. This is easily achieved in excel by defining each x and y series manually in a scatterplot.
How can this be achieved in R or ggplot2?

I understand that you want Days on the x axis and Percent on the y axis with a separate line for each patient. Here is one method of doing that. I stored the intermediate results to make it easier to understand the data wrangling process.
library(tidyverse)
DF <- read_csv("~/R/Play/Dummy.csv")
#> Warning: One or more parsing issues, call `problems()` on your data frame for details,
#> e.g.:
#>   dat <- vroom(...)
#>   problems(dat)
#> Rows: 32 Columns: 3
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Delimiter: ","
#> chr (1): Patient_ID
#> dbl (2): 1, 2
#> 
#> ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
#> ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.

DF2 <- DF |>  rename("P1" = `1`, "P2" = `2`) |> filter(!is.na(P1) | !is.na(P2)) 
DF3 <- DF2 |> pivot_longer(cols = c("P1","P2"),names_to = "Patient")
DF4 <- DF3 |> separate("Patient_ID", into = c("Control", "Measure", "Index"))
DF5 <- DF4 |> pivot_wider(names_from = "Measure", values_from = "value" )
DF5
#> # A tibble: 26 × 5
#>    Control  Index Patient Percent  Days
#>    <chr>    <chr> <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 Controll 1     P1        0        33
#>  2 Controll 1     P2        0        32
#>  3 Controll 2     P1        0.035   378
#>  4 Controll 2     P2        0       128
#>  5 Controll 3     P1        0.035   575
#>  6 Controll 3     P2        0.039   502
#>  7 Controll 4     P1        0.053   951
#>  8 Controll 4     P2        0.053   633
#>  9 Controll 5     P1        0.088  1127
#> 10 Controll 5     P2        0.066   800
#> # ℹ 16 more rows
ggplot(DF5, aes(x = Days, y = Percent, color = Patient, group = Patient)) + 
  geom_line() +geom_point()
#> Warning: Removed 3 rows containing missing values or values outside the scale range
#> (`geom_line()`).
#> Warning: Removed 3 rows containing missing values or values outside the scale range
#> (`geom_point()`).


Created on 2024-10-26 with reprex v2.1.1

Thank you! I see that you have used pivot_wider(). While I have been looking into how to solve this, I had thought that pivot_longer() from the tinyverse would have been ideal, as per https://epirhandbook.com/new_pages/pivoting.html#pivoting-data-of-multiple-classes, which solves a similar issue. Have I missed the point?

You are right that pivot_longer is part of the solution. The label for each patient is in column headers, originally 1 and 2 and changed to P1 and P2. pivot_longer moves that information to a new column named Patient where ggplot can use it. The problem addressed with pivot_wider is that the labels for Percentage and Days  are in a single column. An xy plot needs those values in two columns. Basically, the original data layout was exactly wrong for ggplot and it had to be pivoted twice.

Thanks. Patient ID 1 and 2 were just placeholders for unique patient identfiers which are just integers, and there are several thousand of them.  Is there a way of changing the DF2 and DF3 lines to the fit the general case, not just for PID 1 and 2?

You can make DF3 in one step:
`DF3 <- DF |> pivot_longer(cols = -c("Patient_ID"),names_to = "Patient")
